# How to change Python Qt binding?

Tags: ros, gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [`rqt`'s plugin tutorial in `python`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin), using `qt_binding_helper` is recommended/required for making plugin developers not to care which `python` - `qt` binding to use (namely either `PyQt` or `PySide`). But looks like `qt_binding_helper` internally uses `PyQt` by default. How can I change to `PySide`?

I tried following and still didn't work as I kind of expected.

```
from python_qt_binding.QtBindingHelper import select_qt_binding
:
class RealityWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, context, node=None):        
        :
        select_qt_binding('pyside') # P.S.2
        loadUi(ui_file, self)
```

P.S.1 The reason I want to use `PySide` is first of all I like to avoid `GPL` that `PyQt` requires (as mentioned in [`python_qt_binding`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/python_qt_binding)'s wiki as well). Another trigger is that my code experiences [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395296/typeerror-could-not-convert) where using `PyQt` yields runtime error while `PySide` doesn't. This doesn't mean I have to use `PySide` but just want to avoid any possible unknown issues.

P.S.2 [`select_qt_binding`](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/python_qt_binding/html/namespacepython__qt__binding_1_1QtBindingHelper.html#a60d787f9b6722a2a2d4890ad80d21afb)

---

Update 9/17/12) As far as I searched my file system, no module uses `python_qt_binding.QtBindingHelper.select_qt_binding`.

[`__init__.py` in `rviz`](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/visualization/branches/visualization-1.8/rviz/src/python_bindings/rviz/__init__.py?rev=39164) suggests that:

```
# Can use the following setattr() call to force one binding or the other.
# setattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING', 'pyside')
```

But tyring to use like this it only fails to show still `pyqt` is in use:

```
import os
import sys
import rospy
import rosnode
setattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING', 'pyside')        
from qt_gui.qt_binding_helper import loadUi
from python_qt_binding.QtBindingHelper import select_qt_binding, QT_BINDING 
from QtGui import QWidget, QTreeWidgetItem

class RealityWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, context, node=None):
        select_qt_binding('pyside')
        print ('QT_BINDING=' + QT_BINDING) # this prints "pyqt"
        :
        ui_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'reality.ui')
        loadUi(ui_file, self)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43817/how-to-change-python-qt-binding?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using `setattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING', 'pyside')` works, if it is executed before the first import of python_qt_binding.
But if your code is running as a rqt plugin, rqt has already imported python_qt_binding, so your plugin cannot change the binding anymore.

To run rqt_gui (and therefore your plugin) with a specific binding use the command line option '--qt-binding' or '-b':

`rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui --qt-binding=pyside`

For more command line options see `rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui -h`.

rqt will also choose PySide, if PyQt is not installed on the system.

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1